# How to read and save data on one char? (fstream)

Tags: c++

I need to save and read one char at a time.

I can only use fstream
i can't use ifstream and ofstream

**read**

```
// I hope I'm doing it right
fstream fs("txt.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | ios::binary);
for (char i; fs.get(i);)
{
    cout << i;
}
```

**write**

```
fstream fs("txt.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | ios::binary);
//does not work
for (char i = 't'; fs.put(i);)
{
    cout << i;
}
```

Comment: The opposite of "get" is very often named "put".

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried to use put, but this does not work.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a useful problem description. If you post your attempt, someone can probably tell you what you did wrong. (Read about the [mcve].)

Comment: @molbdnilo added code as I did.

Comment: What do you think the value of `i` is?

Comment: @molbdnilo I just add 1 character there.

Comment: Read this thread hope it will help you -> https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-read-and-write-to-same-file-at-same-time.2068136/

Comment: @Kalana I do not understand why `put` does not work because of `fstream::in |`

Comment: I exactly have no idea because I am not expert at that side of c++. There for I have shared that link with you. sorry about that

Comment: What kind of data is present in the file? Can you give the example?

Comment: What exactly does not work? The loop in `write` will never stop and is only writing a single character until you kill the program. Except from that logic error it works fine for me. Keep in mind, that streams are buffered, which means, that changes you write to the file may not be immediately visible in the actual file.